# Как связать свойство инфоблока с значением поля input? Или как реализовать передачу UTM-меток в почтовый шаблон?

Tags: битрикс

Как передать utm-метки на почтовый ящик вместе с данными формы после отправки формы:

```
<input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_source']) ? $_GET['utm_source'] : '' ;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="utm_medium" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_medium']) ? $_GET['utm_medium'] : '' ;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="utm_campaign" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_campaign']) ? $_GET['utm_campaign'] : '' ;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="utm_term" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_term']) ? $_GET['utm_term'] : '' ;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="utm_content" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_content']) ? $_GET['utm_content'] : '' ;?>">
<input class="button btn1 btn1-item-inner" type="submit" name="efbf_submit" value="Отправить заявку" />
```

Создал в инфоблоке свойства по примеру каждого input, как связать две эти сущности?

Comment: "покажите код" (с): где вы добавили эти поля? В какой форме?
Куда вы ее отправляете? Что в том файле находится?

Answer (score 0):

В mail.php забираешь и передаешь

```
$utmsource = $_POST['source']; // UTM
$utmmedium = $_POST['medium']; // UTM 
$utmcampaign = $_POST['campaign']; // UTM
$utmterm = $_POST['term']; // UTM
$utmcontent = $_POST['content']; // UTM

$message = "
source: $utmsource
medium: $utmmedium
campaign: $utmcampaign
term: $utmterm
content: $utmcontent 
";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```